# build array of uneven matrices in r

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

I am trying to build an array with uneven matrices. The end objective to calculate the average all the matrices to create a final matrix. My code worked when the matrices had the same size and same dimnames. Now I am expanding the inputs but the problem is they don't all have the same dimnames.

Here is simplified code that worked previously:

```
labs <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

dists <- array(0,
    c(length(labs),
        length(labs),
        length(input)),
    dimnames=list(labs, labs))

for (i in 1:length(input)) {
    d <- input[[i]] #short cut to replace bunch of code to create input 
    #class(d) "matrix" "arrary"
    #rownames(d) and colnames(d) would be A, B, C, D in a complete matrix.
    dists[,, i] <- d[labs, labs] #Now ERRORS HERE with uneven d
    }

avg_dists <- apply(dists, c(1, 2), mean)
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213463/combining-matrices-into-an-array-in-r) post, perhaps I need to use abind but not sure how to apply that in my loop above.
I tried essentially building the initial array using the largest/complete labs as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513862/equalizing-matrices-for-combining-in-abind-r) but it errors with subscript out of bounds and again not sure how to apply that in the loop here.

Help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Per the comment below I'm adding in some sample input data:

```
a <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
b <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
c <- matrix(1:8, 4, 4)
colnames(c) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
rownames(c) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
colnames(b) <- c("A", "B", "C")
rownames(b) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(a) <- c("A", "B")
rownames(a) <- c("A", "B")

input <- list(a,b,c)
```

The desired output would be a matrix of the average distances (the input are distance matrices) as such:

```
<avg_dists

  A B   C  D
A 1 4   4  5
B 2 5   6  6
C 3 6.5 6 7
D 4 8   4 8
```

Comment: It is going to be difficult to help without an actual example of the error that you face.

Comment: @RonakShah. Sorry my post isn't clear. I mention above: the error I get is "subscript out of bounds"  at the line `dists[,, i] <- d[labs, labs]` due to unequal labs.

Comment: ok..and what is the final output (with values) that you are looking for the `input` that you have shared?

Comment: @RonakShah I've added the resulting desired output - which would be a matrix of averages resulting from the last line of code originally shared: `avg_dists <- apply(dists, c(1, 2), mean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the list of matrices like this

```
flatinput <- do.call(rbind, lapply(input, as.data.frame.table, responseName = "dist"))
```

After flattening

```
> head(flatinput)

  Var1 Var2 dist
1    A    A    1
2    B    A    2
3    A    B    3
4    B    B    4
5    A    A    1
6    B    A    2
```

Then just `tapply`

```
tapply(flatinput$dist, unname(flatinput[, -3L]), mean)
```

Output

```
  A   B C D
A 1 4.0 4 5
B 2 5.0 5 6
C 3 6.5 6 7
D 4 8.0 4 8
```

Comment: Okay, wow this worked great and allowed me to simply all the rest of my code. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rowname as new column in each of the list, `merge` them together and take `mean` of all columns based on `rowid`.

```
aggregate(.~rowid, Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), 
       lapply(input, function(x) transform(data.frame(x), rowid = rownames(x)))),
              mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)

#  rowid A   B C D
#1     A 1 4.0 4 5
#2     B 2 5.0 5 6
#3     C 3 6.5 6 7
#4     D 4 8.0 4 8
```

Comment: Thank you so much too! Unfortunately, my actual data was so large this hung for some time before finishing. Thank you though.